# Tag Merge/Synonym: [copy-paste]->[clipboard]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

The [copy-paste](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste) tag is used for the clipboard actions Copying and Pasting.

This should be merged with the existing [clipboard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clipboard) tag, and synonymised so that future users can find the right tag.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I think we should also merge a couple of more tags into [clipboard](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/clipboard):

- [copy](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy) (554)
- [copy-paste](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/copy-paste) (350)
- [paste](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/paste) (54)
- [cut-and-paste](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cut-and-paste) (30)

Some might have to be cleanup up though.

Comment: [tag:copy] can be about commands like xcopy32 or ɪꜱᴏ burning. In that case they don’t involve a clipboard.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure "clipboard" should be the primary term.  People think of "clipboard" as a system utility that can be used within or across applications.  A big portion of the copy and copy-paste questions relate to things like propagating cell contents in a spreadsheet.  Copy-paste is more generic than clipboard.

Comment: Most, if not all spreadsheet applications these days support cell propagation in a pretty standardised way - shouldn't it be enough to tag with the software they're using without needing a tag for the specific feature?